# ffmpeg: Cannot read RTMP handshake response

Tags: ffmpeg

I am running ffmpeg version 4.1.11-0+deb10u1 and I am receiving the following error message when running a bash script which worked fine before for almost a year or so:

```
Cannot read RTMP handshake response rtmp://*IP-address:port*
/bcs/channel0_ext.bcs?channel=0&stream=2&user=*XXX*&password=*YYY*: End of file
```

It seems - but I am not sure - that this has to do with an update of the Debian server some days ago.

Maybe I need to update ffmpeg also? If yes, could you tell me how to do this via command line?

Comment: is `IP-address` in `IP-address:port` your server? in Debian, you would `apt update && apt upgrade` to upgrade everything, including ffmpeg, so, if you had a recent upgrade, then ffmpeg is likely the highest version available for your Debian (seems it's Debian 10/Buster)

Comment: I have done `apt update && apt upgrade`

yes, I have Debian 10/Buster (shown at lsb_release -a) 
`ffmpeg -version`  shows the following:
`ffmpeg version 4.1.11-0+deb10u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)`

Comment: The problem still persist. 
IP-address in IP-address:port is the webcam in my boat which I reach via OpenVPN from the server running ffmpeg and running the script which is causing the above mentioned error message

Comment: using 'rtmp://*IP-address:port*
/bcs/channel0_ext.bcs?channel=0&stream=2&user=*XXX*&password=*YYY*' is working in VLC player on a windows notebook also connected from externally via OpenVPN to this webcam. But for some reason via ffmpeg it does no longer work.